# How to use navigation on react, which will work both web and mobile?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-dom, react-native-web

I am not able to load the @react-navigation/web, In React-navigation 5x. It is removed, then how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using React Navigation 5 on a React Native Web application, I can confirm everything works flawlessly when you follow the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/web-support

Comment: Hi Bro, I followed the config things, but failed. Can you elaborate little bit more. Please

Comment: Actually, I am new to this topic. Please give some advice what after what.. As a beginner i wanted to understand it in prior. Thanks in advance bro.